# How to Pass Data Between Activities in Android Studion; The Whole Extras Dataset

Tags: android, android-studio

There are a number of questions and answers dealing with the passing of data between activities in Android, but all these use the named-key data pairs:

```
string dataToPass= "Hello I am activity one";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("KeyToAccessData", dataToPass);   //the usual method
startActivity(intent);
```

But I have a situation where I need to get the whole extras array (I presume it is an array of some sort, key pairs), and pass it to the next activity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

How can the above **extras** be injected wholly into the new Intent? Is it even possible?

The objective is to preserve the named keys and values as they come from different activities and they may vary, and on some failures, the original re-entry will be simulated in this activity.

Comment: You can pass extras as a bundle in intent.putExtra(key, extras)

Answer (score 0):

As a complete question and answer, I am adding to @Abdullah_Javed comment:

```
//passing the whole extras dataset to an activity
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  //get the whole bundle 
 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("prevExtras", extras );   //the whole bundle;
startActivity(intent);

//getting the previous extras
Intent newIntent = getIntent();
Bundle prevExtras = newIntent.getBundleExtra("prevExtras");
```

This is tested to work.